# Does LinQ Any() cast all items in a collection?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I know when Linq's `Any()` extension is used to determine if an enumerable has at least one element it will only consume a single element.  But how does that work actually?  Does it have to cast all items in the enumerable first, or does it just cast them one at a time, starting with the first and stopping there?

Comment: Why would you even suspect that a cast is involved at all?

Comment: I suspect you are using 'cast' to mean something other than the generally accepted meaning. What do you think it means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Any()` works on an `IEnumerable<T>` so no cast is required. It's implementation is very simple, it simply iterates through the enumerable and sees if it can find any elements matching the specified criteria.

Comment: That's for the overload that takes a function, the other parameterless overload, while sharing a name, acts quite differently.

Comment: True. Not all versions take a predicate. But the general idea is the same: Are there any elements, optionally, that match a given criteria? In either case, no conversion is needed on the data.

Comment: And the version that does not take a predicate is basically a shim for `Any(x => true)`.

Answer (score 2):

Simple implementation looks like:

```
public bool Any<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    using (var enumerator = list.GetEnumerator())
    {
        return enumerator.MoveNext();
    }
}
```

So, no any casting required

Comment: The LINQ version is generic, and you need to dispose of the enumerator, and you don't null check your input sequence, but other than that it's morally the same.

Comment: @Servy: Thanks, I know, just simplify it for easy understanding

Comment: The null check and generics aren't that important, but disposing of the enumerator really is, and shouldn't be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Code in the public static class `Enumerable`:

```
public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source) {
    if(source==null) {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    using(IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator=source.GetEnumerator()) {
        if(enumerator.MoveNext()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public static bool Any<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) {
    if(source==null) {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    if(predicate==null) {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("predicate");
    }
    foreach(TSource local in source) {
        if(predicate(local)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Not seen the casting, but generic.